# Error: Unauthorized: Your client does not have permission to the requested URL while sending gRPC request to service hosted on Cloud Run

Tags: python, authentication, grpc, google-cloud-run, grpc-python

I would like to deploy my grpc service to Cloud Run and send authenticated requests to it via Python3. I have followed various Documents regarding setting establishing authentication to Google Cloud Run Services and have been recieving grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError errors:

my client code is as follows:

```
#server_info='<service url>:443'
credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
channel = google.auth.transport.grpc.secure_authorized_channel(
            credentials, request, server_info,
            ssl_credentials=grpc.ssl_channel_credentials())

stub = myClient_pb2_grpc.MyGrpcClientPBStub(channel)
```

I have assigned myself 'Cloud Run Invoker' role for this service. I am also the owner of the Service account associated with this service.

I ran `gcloud auth application-default` and executing client code produces the error:

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED
 debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  ipv4:xxx.xxx.xx.xx:443:
```

I have tried manually downloading the associated Service Account's .json key for this project and assigned it to the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable. and executing client code produces the error:

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer <service url>:443
```

Any pointers to properly authenticate would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a well-written first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's confusing and it's poorly-documented.

The issue is that you need an ID token including an `audience` (claim) of the Cloud Run service's address. The credentials that you're getting from [`google.auth.credentials.Credentials`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials) provide an access token.

See this [`grpc_client.py`](https://github.com/salrashid123/grpc_google_id_tokens/blob/master/python/grpc_client.py) and the associated [`README`](https://github.com/salrashid123/grpc_google_id_tokens) and note that the blog post he references is now here [gRPC auth with OpenID Connect tokens](https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2019/grpc_google_id_tokens/).

**NOTE** It's unclear to my why you're getting a different error `StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED` when using using user credentials as Application Default Credentials (ADC) and `StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED` when using a Service Account for ADC.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I was hoping you could clarify some information I couldn't find in the readme. so the ca_certificate is a certificate that we generate on our own? (such as openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048).

Comment: target_audience would be the address of my service in this case? im confused why address = 'localhost:8080' is being used as the target; why would this not be our service endpoint? Im assuming server_sni_name = 'grpc.domain.com' is a universal name for the grpc header?

Comment: Ignore `ca_certificate`, you can use `grpc.ssl_channel_credentials())`.

Comment: `target` is the Cloud Run service's endpoint **without** the scheme (i.e. no `https://`) and **with** the port (i.e. `:443`). `audience` is the service's endpoint as-is (i.e with the `https://`) and **without** the port.

Comment: You can omit the `server_sni_name`, `grpc_channel_options` and `options=grpc_channel_options` too.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it.